# spark emr job, executors being lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

Hi i have a spark submit job/step that is running continuously without failing but losing executors. The data increases everyday, initially it ran fine but now with 400gb of data in s3 it seems (at least what i think is that there isn't enough resource

I am using , 18 r3.8xlarge for this.

```
                "EMR_MasterInstanceType": "r3.xlarge",
                "EMR_CoreInstanceType": "r3.8xlarge",
                "EMR_CoreInstanceCount": "18",
```

`"Step2_Spark_Command": "command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--class,com.lex.rex.link.modules.multipart_files.files,--name,\\\"Multipart Files Module\\\",--master,yarn,--deploy-mode,client,--executor-memory,22G,--executor-cores,4,--conf,spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=320,/home/hadoop/linking.jar,jobId=#{myJobId},environment=test",`

Any thoughts or insight?
is the current configuration sufficent?

If i am using 18 ec2 instances of r3.8xl and 22G executor memory i would have 396G of ram for in memory processing? is my assumption even correct?

400gb > 396gb is that why it's failing?

Comment: 396GB of memory is not **necessarily** enough for 400GB of input. **It depends on what the application actually does**. What if your application is caching 5 data frames or RDDs of 300GB each, all derived from the same input? What does your UI say about what's keeping the cluster busy during job execution? Why do you suspect this is a memory problem?

Comment: is my assumption correct , 18 ec2 r3.8xl instance x 22G of executor memory? 18 X 22 = 396GB?

Comment: Again, not necessarily. It depends on the number of executors you're giving to your application, as well as the amount of memory per executor. Remember that you're mentioning OS memory, which will simply not be fully usable in spark

Comment: i didn't specify any other property, if it's default than it would 1 executor?

Comment: Well, you could try first counting one executor per worker machine (`--num-executors <number>` is the `spark-submit` parameter), but you'll have to use your UI to see how the cluster does when the job runs

Answer (score 0):

Wondering what's the number of executors？

Assuming that the ERROR info is **ExecutorLostFailure (executor lost).**

It's mostly caused by inadequate resources, which causes bad performance for executor, such as badly GC. You can increase the app's resource by increasing the number of executors. If not, you can do some tuning, like increase the value of:
`spark.shuffle.io.retryWait, spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries`

Comment: is my assumption correct , 18 ec2 r3.8xl instance x 22G of executor memory? 18 X 22 = 396GB?

Comment: You can go to app's web UI -> Executors tab to verify this.

Comment: we have enabled dynamic allocation. i think that means executors are set by yarn